# React Native :after styling like css

Tags: react-native

How do style in react-native like we do in sass

```css
.pro_image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
}
```

because I tried using the same technique but it seems not to be working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Css pseudo classes do not work in react-native, but if you want your styles to look as close to css as possible I would recommend using something like [Styled Components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics). It works on both web and react-native.

Comment: How exactly can this be done, I tried &:before, but it gave me an error.

Comment: styled-components/native does not support pseudo selectors